# Call a url in javascript on click

Tags: javascript, jsp, url

I have a javascript function. On-click will call this. Using `document.getElementById` I am getting certain parameters there. Using that parameters I need to build a url. ie, onclick will have to execute that url.

For example, in javascript,

```
function remove()
{
var name=...;
var age = ...;
// url should be like http://something.jsp?name=name&age=age
}
```

In short I need to execute `http://something.jsp?name=name&age=age` this url on click

```
<input type="button" name="button" onclick="remove();" />
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

```
function remove()
{
    var name = ...;
    var age  = ...;

    window.location = 'http://something.jsp?name=' + name + '&age=' + age;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I use:

```
document.location.href = "report.html";
```

So, in your case:

```
function remove() {
    var name=... ,
        age = ...;

    document.location.href = "something.jsp?name=" + name + "&age=" + age;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

just call

```
window.location=myURL;
```

in your function